# Grouping users by privilege using Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have a task: Given a list of users each one with some privileges, group users by privileges. I should use the stream API. This is the only code, which came to my mind:

```
public Map<Privilege, List<User>> groupByPrivileges(List<User> users) {
    return users.stream().collect(groupingBy(User::getPrivileges));
}
```

As you can see in the return type of the method, I need to get a map with single Privilege objects as keys, but a User may appear multiple times, under different keys, if they have multiple privileges.

The main problem is that `User::getPrivilege`s returns `List<Privilege>`, and I know only how to process a single `Privilege`.

Comment: What is what you need?

Comment: *But that's not what I need* - unfortunately we are not in the field of reading minds.

Comment: You have a missing parenthesis and it should be `Collectors.groupingBy` unless you have a `static` import. Fixing those two things makes it compile for me

Comment: @GBlodgett, sorry if I was unclear, I need to "group users by privileges". It is specified in my task description.

Comment: What does "group users by priveleges" mean? How is the code you have not what you want?

Comment: show the `Privilege` @Kushnir_Andrey

Comment: The main problem is that User::getPrivileges returs List<Privelege>, and i know only how to process Privelege

Comment: @Deadpool, this is a user method: `public List<Privilege> getPrivileges() {
        return privileges;
    }`

Comment: So the map still should have single `Privilege` objects as key, but a `User` may appear multiple times, under different keys if they have multiple privileges?

Comment: that's not going to help us, please show something with input and out example

Comment: @Holger, exactly.

Comment: Then [edit] the question and add these information…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an entry for each privilege in the list and then group by when you collect as :

```
public Map<Privilege, List<User>> groupByPrivileges(List<User> users) {
    return users.stream()
            .flatMap(user -> user.getPrivileges().stream()
                    .map(privilege -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(privilege, user)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
}
```